# How to select unique arrays from MySQL table row?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with 20 rows and one row have for example:

```
2,3,5,6,8,22
2,3,5,6,8,22,44,55
etc.
```

How can I select from mysql table rows only unique numbers, not duplicated so results are:

```
2,3,5,6,8,22,44,55
```

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',

  `facilities` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `active`, `facilities`) VALUES

(1, 1, '1,3,5,6,7,8'),

(2, 1, '2,3,4,5,8,9'),

(3, 1, '4,5,6,7,9,10');
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT facilities FROM test WHERE active='1'

$dbgeneral= explode(',', $row['facilities']);


$facilities = array(

"Air Conditioning" => "2",

"Balcony" => "4");

foreach ($facilities as $facilities=> $v) {

     if(in_array($v,$dbgeneral)) {

echo '';

}
}
```

Comment: Is this one field with comma separated numbers?

Comment: could you show the table Definition? SSince althane's answer of distinct could be correct, but does each of your "rows" contain only 1 field? or are their multiple fields?

Comment: Here is my table:

id
2 - 3 - 5  


facilities
1,2,3,4,5,8,9 - 1,7,9,11,13 - 4,5,6,9,10

Comment: I'm still not grasping this concept - could you post the DDL for the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this is only one field, you could do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT facilities FROM table');

$facilities = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    $facilities = array_merge($facilities , explode(',', $row[0]));
}

$facilities = array_unique($facilities);
```

But you should consider to change your database design, it looks like your data is not normalized.

Reference: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

---

Depening on what kind of queries you want to do, a better table layout would be:

```
 | id  | facility |
 |  2  | 1        |
 |  2  | 2        |
 |  2  | 3        |
 ...
 |  3  | 1        |
 |  3  | 7        |
 |  3  | 9        |
 ...
```

and **then** you could just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT facility FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank Felix, it works great! Now I can easily select for example  FIND_IN_SET(2, facilities) OR FIND_IN_SET(6, facilities)